# How to get one letter and one number from REGEX Oracle Sql query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to get just "P1:" from this code but if I add numbers to the one it will output those as well. How do I restrict it to only take numbers 1-9 and have it display "NULL" if it's two digits?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('P1:EMAIL', '[P]+\d+[:]') as test from dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the `+` operator, which means [match one *or more* of the character or class](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm). If you want to match exactly one then you don't want that. You also don't need the square brackets:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('P1:EMAIL', 'P\d:') as test from dual;
```

You might also want to anchor the pattern to the start of the string, but that isn't clear; if so then:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('P1:EMAIL', '^P\d:') as test from dual;
```

Comment: Great! Just starting out in this, having a hard time grasping some things. Essentially I just need the "P-[1-4]-:" in the code,  but my concern is the program might output multiple digits, like
 'P4453:' Is there a way to get JUST the P, the digit directly after it, then the : on the end?